# Problem with apt-get for kernel sources

Tags: apt, kernel, source-code

I am running Ubuntu desktop 16.04
I tried to get the kernel sources using the command

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

as recommended in the Ubuntu wiki.
I got the error

```
E: You must put some source URIs in your sources.list
```

I searched the web and found advice on editing sources.list, but don't know what specifically I need to do to get the kernel sources. I am new to this; can someone help?

Comment: Specifically for the kernel, you need at least one `deb-src` line with `main` in it.

Comment: OK., so I tried editing the sources.list file, but of course, it is read-only. The system keeps asking me for the root (or sudo) password, but I was not asked to specify one when installing the system (which I did by running the standard UI-based install onto a VM. How do I find the root password?

Comment: You might have to reset (!) it: http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/158442

Comment: Thanks Muru. I edited the sources.list file and uncommented the deb-src lines that were present. One such line is "deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xental main restricted" and other similar lines for updates, etc.

Comment: Now it proceeds a little further, saying "Reading package lists ... Done" before giving the same error (E: You must put some source URIs in your sources.list). Is there some specific line I must add to this file?

Comment: did you run `sudo apt-get update` after modifying that file?